# How to design solution for querying 200k+ records and using that inside LWC?

Tags: soql, batch, lightning-web-components, governorlimits

[image]

I have a problem statement where I need to design an LWC component to enter policy information and check if that policy already exists in the system and print a report of those that aren't in the system. I was able to achieve this in sandbox where I have <500 policy records to fetch and compare with. But in production, there are more than 200k records. So, the query hits the governor limit of 50000.
I initially thought I will ass LIMIT 50000 to the query on policies, but then realized, it will not work on the remaining 150k+ policies. The next solution was to implement a batch class to query and return the results. I did it like so:

```
global class KI_PolicyGridController_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

    List<Policy__c> allPolicies = new List<Policy__c>();

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String Query = 'SELECT Id, Product__c, Effective_Date__c, Policy_Holder__r.FirstName, Policy_Holder__r.LastName, Policy_Holder__r.Medicare_Number__c'
                      +' FROM Policy__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Policy__c> polList){
        system.debug('****polList.size(): '+polList.size());
        allPolicies.addAll(polList);
        system.debug('****allPolicies.size(): '+allPolicies.size());
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        getAllPolicies();
    }

    public List<Policy__c> getAllPolicies(){
        return allPolicies;
    }
}
```

The debug statement: 
system.debug('****allPolicies.size(): '+allPolicies.size()); 
returns the total number of records present in the system.

I need to capture this inside my auraEnabled method in the controller:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Policy__c> fetchPolicies(){

       KI_PolicyGridController_Batch batch = new KI_PolicyGridController_Batch();
       Database.executeBatch(batch, 200);
       system.debug('****batch.allPolicies.size(): '+batch.getAllPolicies().size());

       return batch.getAllPolicies();

    }
```

But the problem here is that the batch class executes asynchronously. So I don't understand how to get all those policies so that I can compare them inside the javaScript controller like so:

```
@track polcomp;
//fetch the policy fields to compare from the controller
    _wiredComp;
    @wire(fetchPolicies)
    wiredCallback1(result) {
        this._wiredComp = result;
        if (result.data) {
        this.polcomp = result.data;
        this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error;
        this.polcomp = undefined;
        }
    }

//compare polices with selected policy checks
    redirect(evt) {
        //if statement to make sure atleast 1 check has been selected
        if(counter > 0){
            var list = [];
            var fields = {};
            for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {

                for (var z = 0; z < this.polcomp.length; z++) {
                    if (this.polcomp[z].Product__c == selected[k].product &&
                        this.polcomp[z].Policy_Holder__r.FirstName.toLowerCase() ==
                        selected[k].first.toLowerCase() &&
                        this.polcomp[z].Policy_Holder__r.LastName.toLowerCase() ==
                        selected[k].last.toLowerCase() &&
                        this.polcomp[z].Policy_Holder__r.Medicare_Number__c.toLowerCase() ==
                        selected[k].medicare.toLowerCase() &&
                        this.polcomp[z].Effective_Date__c == selected[k].date){

                        // Set the policy check success to true if conditions are met
                        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = selected[k].id;
                        fields[CHECK_FIELD.fieldApiName] = true;
                        list = { fields };
                        updateRecord(list);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log('***this.polcomp.length: '+this.polcomp.length);
            console.log('***selected.length: '+selected.length);

            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();

            //set navigation to report parameters
            this.accountHomePageRef = {
                type: "standard__recordPage",
                attributes: {
                recordId: reportId,
                actionName: "view"
                }
            };

            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.accountHomePageRef).then(url => {
                location.reload();
            });
        }

        //error if atleast one check isn't selected
        if (counter == 0) {
            const evt1 = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Error",
                message: "Please select atleast one row.",
                variant: "error"
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt1);
        }
    }
```

console.log('***this.polcomp.length: '+this.polcomp.length); -- this prints 0.

Could anyone post their suggessions to solve the problem statement described above?

Comment: In my experience no one will be happy to look at 50K applications in a single screen, let allone 200K means bad experience .

Batch cant returns you 200k records, they can process large number records cant return you them to be displayed in the screen.

Comment: Why do you wanna display 200k records? cant they use reports?

Comment: I am not going to display all of them in the UI. Im querying them and comparing them agains few selected records

Comment: So if you see the image I updated in the question, the user will enter some policy information manually, then click on the check policies button. This will compare the 200k policies stored in the system to check if these records already exist in the system.

Comment: Instead of querrying all 200k records just querry a limited by adding filter in SOQL?

Comment: If i add a limit 1000 for example, won’t that ignore the remaining records and avoid comparing those?

Comment: What do you mean "print a report of those that aren't in the system"?  If they're not in the system, how can they appear on the report?

Comment: The user gets policy information on paper and goes into the policy grid component to enter those details. these details are saved in an object called PolicyCheck__c. The image you see above is the information entered by user saved into PolicyCheck__c. The parameters between policy and PolicyCheck are compared. If they don’t match, then i fetch a report of PolicyChecks i.e policies that don’t exist in the system.

Comment: You seem to have approached this problem a bit incorrectly. If you already are asking the User to enter a *criteria* based on which you will compare the policies, you need a [Selective SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm) here. You will just need to include those conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Refer to the link to the documentation for details around this topic which deals with LDV.

Comment: Agreed! Changed soql to include where clause. It’s resolved now. Thank you.